# Arduino IDE isn't starting on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, arduino

I've tried to restart my PC, uninstalled and reinstalled, and I've tried older versions but the thing still won't start. I've also turned off my antivirus and firewall but that didn't work either. I just ran the debug and this is what it said:

```
Loading configuration...
Initializing packages...
Preparing boards...
java.io.IOException: The cloud file provider is not running
        at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
        at processing.app.legacy.PApplet.loadStrings(PApplet.java:270)
        at processing.app.helpers.PreferencesMap.load(PreferencesMap.java:100)
        at processing.app.helpers.PreferencesMap.load(PreferencesMap.java:74)
        at processing.app.packages.UserLibrary.create(UserLibrary.java:65)
        at cc.arduino.contributions.libraries.LibrariesIndexer.scanLibrary(LibrariesIndexer.java:188)
        at cc.arduino.contributions.libraries.LibrariesIndexer.scanInstalledLibraries(LibrariesIndexer.java:157)
        at cc.arduino.contributions.libraries.LibrariesIndexer.rescanLibraries(LibrariesIndexer.java:124)
        at cc.arduino.contributions.libraries.LibrariesIndexer.setLibrariesFolders(LibrariesIndexer.java:106)
        at processing.app.BaseNoGui.onBoardOrPortChange(BaseNoGui.java:682)
        at processing.app.Base.onBoardOrPortChange(Base.java:1297)
        at processing.app.Base$11.actionPerformed(Base.java:1498)
        at processing.app.Base.rebuildBoardsMenu(Base.java:1474)
        at processing.app.Base.<init>(Base.java:262)
        at processing.app.Base.main(Base.java:140)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at processing.app.helpers.PreferencesMap.load(PreferencesMap.java:101)
        at processing.app.helpers.PreferencesMap.load(PreferencesMap.java:74)
        at processing.app.packages.UserLibrary.create(UserLibrary.java:65)
        at cc.arduino.contributions.libraries.LibrariesIndexer.scanLibrary(LibrariesIndexer.java:188)
        at cc.arduino.contributions.libraries.LibrariesIndexer.scanInstalledLibraries(LibrariesIndexer.java:157)
        at cc.arduino.contributions.libraries.LibrariesIndexer.rescanLibraries(LibrariesIndexer.java:124)
        at cc.arduino.contributions.libraries.LibrariesIndexer.setLibrariesFolders(LibrariesIndexer.java:106)
        at processing.app.BaseNoGui.onBoardOrPortChange(BaseNoGui.java:682)
        at processing.app.Base.onBoardOrPortChange(Base.java:1297)
        at processing.app.Base$11.actionPerformed(Base.java:1498)
        at processing.app.Base.rebuildBoardsMenu(Base.java:1474)
        at processing.app.Base.<init>(Base.java:262)
        at processing.app.Base.main(Base.java:140)
```

Can anyone please make sense of this and help me? I just got a mega 2560 and a bunch of parts and I'm eager to try them out.

Answer (score 0):

Select a different version of windows from the compatibility settings and try.
example Windows 8, Windows 7

Comment: Where would compatibility settings be found at?

Comment: Right-click the app, click properties, then access the compatibility tab